# QGis server : 0 is wrote instead of "null"

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-server, null

I am trying to load PostGis data on QGis (client) with QGis server (WFS).

Unfortunately, missing values and NULL values for numbers appear as 0.

Here is what I tried:

specified variable QGIS_OPTIONS_PATH in file conf "httpd-qgis.conf" Apache (on Windows)

```
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_OPTIONS_PATH "my\path\"
```

I placed a file at my\path\QGIS\QGIS2.ini

Content of the file:

```
[Qgis]
nullValue=NULL
```

It don't work !

Do you have any idea what I did wrong that NULL values still don't work
in QGIS Server ?

Comment: I would hazard a guess and ask if the data is in a table and the column is a number data type (integer, float, double, etc)?  If so, in my experience, those data types return a zero value since they are only allowed to accept numbers.

Comment: I tested with "numeric" type it is OK the NULL values are displayed NULL but with the type "integer" this does not work. NULL values are displayed 0. Problem is WFS or QGis server.

Comment: In the comment GIS87 wrote, "numeric" type is a more broad numerical type and therefor supports values such as NULL to be displayed as NULL. But a strong type, like integer, float, double do not allow NULL values to appear and translates them to 0.